# Erro index, ME AJUDEM POR FAVOR

Tags: php, mysqli

tentei de tudo, não sei porque esta dando erro, ME AJUDEM POR FAVOR
O ERRO É: 
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: usuario_id in C:\wamp64\www\completo\tabela\excluirAdminUserDoador.php on line 2

CÓDIGO HTML:

```
<?php  

session_start();
include('../verifica_login.php');
$nome = $_SESSION['nome'];

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login"); 
$query ="SELECT * FROM usuariodoador ORDER BY usuario_id DESC";

 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  

 ?>  

 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Donatário</title>  

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />

           <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />-->
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container">  
                   <h3 align="center">Logins de donatarios</h3><h4>Olá, <?php echo $nome;?>, <a href="tabelaTesteAdmin.php">Ir para doadores</a></h4><a href="menuAdmin.php">voltar</a></h4>  
                <br /> <br> 
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered">  
                          <thead>  

                               <tr>  
                                 <div class="cell">
                                    <td>RA</td>
                                  </div>
                                 <div class="cell">
                                    <td>Nome</td> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cell">
                                    <td>Senha criptografada</td>  
                                  </div>
                                    <div class="cell">
                                    <td>Data da criação</td>  
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="cell">
                                    <td>Excluir</td>
                                  <div class="cell">  
                                    <td hidden>Editar</td> 
                                  </div> 

                                  </tr>  
                          </thead>  



                          <?php




                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


                               echo '  
                              <div class="row">
                               <tr> 
                               <div class="cell" data-title="Age"> 
                                    <td >'.$row["usuario_id"].'</td>  
                              </div>
                              <div class="cell" data-title="Full Name">
                                    <td>'.$row["usuario"].'</td>
                              </div>
                                <div class="cell" data-title="Full Name">
                                    <td>'.$row["nome"].'</td>
                              </div>
                              <div class="cell" data-title="Job Title">  
                                    <td>'.$row["senha"].'</td>  
                              </div>
                              <div class="cell" data-title="Location">
                                    <td>'.$row["data_cadastro"].'</td>  
                              </div>

                              <div class="cell" data-title="Location">
                             <td>
                              <a href="excluirAdminUserDoador.php?usuario_id='.$row['usuario_id'].'">Excluir
                              </a>
                              </td>
                            </div>





                               </tr>  

                               ';  
                           }
                          ?>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#employee_data').DataTable();  
 });  
 </script>  

   <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#minhaTabela').DataTable({
          "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ registros por página",
                "zeroRecords": "Nada encontrado",
                "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "Nenhum registro disponível",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros no total)"
            }
        });
  });
  </script>
```

CÓDIGO PHP:

```
<?php
$usuario_id = $_GET['usuario_id'];
/*$usuario_id = isset($_POST['usuario_id']) ? $_POST['usuario_id'] : '';*/
include("../conexaoExcluirUser.php");

$sql = "DELETE FROM usuariodoador WHERE usuario_id = $usuario_id";

mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die ("Não foi excluido");

echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Excluido com sucesso!');window.location.href='tabelaTesteAdmin.php'</script>";


?>
```

CÓDIGO CONEXAO:

```
<?php

$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$banco = "login";

$link = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);

?>
```

Comment: `$_GET['usuario_id']` não está definido. Deveria estar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa entender o que é um Notice para depois saber o que fazer para evitá-los. Normalmente ele indica que uma variável, array, constante não pode ser acessada. Porém, implicitamente se ele está ali é porque algo não está sendo tratado corretamente.

É como se o PHP estivesse pensando:

*"Você não deveria estar fazendo o que está fazendo, mas vou permitir mesmo assim".*

Logo, agora sabemos o que algo está errado e a própria mensagem de erro indica onde.
Notice: Undefined index: **usuario_id** (E ainda cita a linha em que algo errado está acontecendo).

Você pode estar pensando, como assim o erro está no usuario_id, se ele recebe o `$_GET['usuario_id']`? Veja bem, está recebendo sim, mas e o `$_GET['usuario_id']` tem algo para passar para a variável? Certamente aí está o problema...

Você pode evitar esse tipo de erro simplesmente verificando a existência da variável e de valores na mesma com um `if`:

```
if (isset($_GET["usuario_id"]) && $_GET["usuario_id"] != '') {
    $usuario_id = $_GET["usuario_id"];
}else{
    echo "Usuario não definido";
    // Demais acoes... Volta para pagina anterior?
}
```

Assim você verifica se a variável e seu índice existem, sem tentar acessar seus valores (que podem não existir), porque neste dado momento o que importa é sua existência, não seu valor.

> Referência:
>
> [PHP: isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php)

Comment: Já que vai usar isset poderia usar algo como (que funciona muito bem com strings): `if (isset($_GET["usuario_id"][0])) {` ou simplesmente usar empty, exemplo: ``if (!empty($_GET["usuario_id"])) {``

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, clara e objetivo!